# OpenCSV Java - CsvToBeanFilter using annotated objects instead of a HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy

Tags: java, opencsv

I'm reading a CSV file and am using a `HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy` to associate columns in my Object to those in the input data and it all works fine.

In addition, I've implemented a `CsvToBeanFilter` to filter out data before the objects are constructed to improve performance.

What I would like to do is move away from `HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy` and move to annotated fields on my object.

The [provided example](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html?com/opencsv/bean/CsvToBeanFilter.html) for `CsvToBeanFilter` however, seem to be referring to the `MappingStrategy` to get the column outside of the object.

Any ideas how I can do this with annotated fields?

From the fact [the supplied documentation doesn't compile, and references a deprecated method](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/bugs/185/) makes me think I might be out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-posting [from the bug report I filed](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/bugs/185/).

> Yeah, you've caught us at an inopertune moment. I became aware of that
>   use for getColumnIndex() after I deprecated it, and the replacement
>   for CsvToBeanFilter (BeanVerifier) is in master, but hasn't been
>   released yet. Right now, just use the deprecated getColumnIndex() if
>   you have to. It should be very easy to move from CsvToBeanFilter to
>   BeanVerifier once 4.4 is released.
>
> I'll take care of the documentation error another time, but thanks
>   very much for pointing it out. I believe in flawless documentation.